# Stack guard exception while using OpenCV for java in eclipse- ubuntu 15.04

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv3.0, ubuntu-15.04

I have installed openCV 3.0.1 in ubuntu 15.04.trying to develop an program image keypoint detection. Here is my java code where error occurs:

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
Mat blurredImage = new Mat();
```

when I compile it in eclipse it generates warning

`OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library opencv-3.1.0/build/lib/libopencv_java310.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now`.

`It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'`.

when I try to use Mat object as shown above it gives me error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat()J
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:24).
```

can anyone help how to fix it?

Comment: The same error. Some enlighment is needed about what is going on.